# input validation

Tags: javascript

How can I check that an input textbox has a float value with no more than 3 places after the point in javascript?

Answer (score 3):

```
if (textbox.value.match(/\d+(\.\d{1,3})?/) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiply it by 1000, subtract the rounded value, and check if it's bigger than 0?

Answer (score 0):

```
/^\d*\.\d{0,3}$/.test(field.value);  // returns true if valid, otherwise returns false
```

Answer (score -2):

thank u guys But i made the solution in a much simpler way :
 1st wrote this function ---->
//Checking A value is 3 decimal palce or not

function chkplace3(ctrl,msg)
{

```
var dot="."
var val = ctrl.value;
var len=val.length
var ldot=val.indexOf(dot)
var diff=(len-ldot)
if(diff>4)
{
    alert(msg + ' can not be more than 3 numeric places');
    ctrl.focus();
    return false;
}
return true;
```

}

and then calling with the reqd parameter from the form --->

if(!chkplace3(document.from.txtfield,'msg'))
    {
        return false;
    }

Comment: That would allow me to enter "abc.def". The regular expression solutions posted by myself and others also check that only digits (0 - 9) are entered.